# ubuntu : right click is acting as left click on context menu

Tags: 16.04, unity, context-menu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, when I right-click an option in a context-menu, it gets selected (as if I left-click it), it is too easy to accidentally select the first context-menu option,

I have read that this problem is well known bug, is there any solution for it ?

Thanks in advance,